# Internet-Explorer: external text files are only available in binary format

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with a strange situation. The problem does always ocurres in Internet-Explorer only. My problem: at my work I have developed a webiste with javascript and css. All javascript sourcecode and css rules are outsourced in external files. For my suprise the javascript code and css rules haven't been invoked. I checked the responsible files, by downloading and opening them into a text editor. When I opened the files they were all in binary format.
Remember: only in Internet-Explorer. In Chrome, Safari and Firefox doesn't exists this problem.

Another strange/funny thing is. I am using a proxy server. When I disabled it, these files are in text format.

The administrators and I have absolutly no idea which option is wrong or is missing. I've got the theory that a mimetype would not be received or wrong , so the browser thinks these are binaries.

Thank in advance

Comment: My first idea: Proxy uses GZIP to forward content but browser maybe didn't allow GZIP (deflated only)... but this is just my two cents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the proxy uses GZIP to forward the content but the browser maybe didn't allow GZIP in the first place (deflated only).