# pdf download from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to download a pdf which i get from a ajax request.

it looks like this in the console:

> <>/Metadata 193 0 R/ViewerPreferences 194 0
>   R>> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0
>   obj <>/ExtGState<>/XObject<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32
>   841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents
>   0>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream
>   x��]*o�6��G��(��(
>   ��������-��&�np];�x��ou��C��lrH���E[ע�7�!�3����/�v���]��ח/v����]������˛?ח׫����a��|���|�z��[?}�M��۫�*�gB���7eS�R%��Np^<�����E�9?�ǉj8�Ƽ�9?�����/n���HQ�I��ZӲ����zثw�x�|~����1=����>���W�g�.�.+n�z~����i�6�)Eu�Ρ��%*<�6��R.6��Xln������[l���Z��T�Ԥ$���O���T�u.����^�ځZ��(����Њ�Bɺd��ר��r�v*��*��ޚ�X��U�
>   ��F��5'e�ӥ*�[hz��cT�44=֨w�춗��n��p�o���7G���$�(��|�L)��m����YS����fZ��+!s�0����b���n��n���cV���"kЮ�D/+^PQ
>   ־

Comment: It is a conflict between your requested encoding and the enabled one on target server.

Comment: @reporter so that means?

Comment: It means: you want to get the pdf and wrote in code uft-8 and on server the encoding is cf-1295. Another possibility is the doesn't support gzip. I don't know the exact reason, but your posted "image" is not unknow for me.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474285/internet-explorer-external-text-files-are-only-available-in-binary-format let you lead into the right way.

Comment: i can download the response but, how can i convert it into a correct pdf file? the downloaded file has the weird content from my post above.

Comment: Have you added the contenttype for pdf, so the browser can see it is a pdf file?

Comment: yes i did in the request     "contentType": "application/pdf"